Solving $ \left|\frac{3x}{7} \right |= 4-x$
I’m trying to solve:
$\displaystyle \left|\frac{3x}{7} \right |= 4-x$
Here’s what I’ve tried:
$\frac{3x}{7} = 4-x$ (checking for intersections)
$x = \frac{14}5$ (this intersection checks out)
Pretending I don’t know what the function $4-x$ looks like, I consider that:
If $\frac{3x}{7} = -(4-x)$, then that should also be an intersection.
Tangent — this is the case for, say, $|2x| = 10$. Finding the value for $x$ where $2x = 10$ gives me one intersection, and finding the value for $x$ where $2x = -10$ gives me an intersection. End tangent.
So, solving for x for the second equation I get 7. But 7 does not actually make the original equation equal.
This exploration is just part of an actual problem I was solving in my book:
$$\left \vert \frac{3x}{7} \right \vert=4-x$$
I believe my book is incorrect but it used the same method I just used to arrive at a range that satisfies the inequality of:
$\frac{14}5 \leq x \leq 7$
But this can’t be true because there’s truly only one intersection ($\frac{14}{5}$) and any values larger satisfy the inequality, not those between it and 7.
Can someone please explain what I and my book are missing? I’m trying to learn a way to systematically (and intuitively) solve these.

Name of the book , page number , citation is taught in highschool.

Please Fix yout math Jax , I fixed the question and title , fix the rest, google mathjax to learn how . At 150 points should have be posting better quality than this

Trivium Air Force Officer Qualifying Test 2023-2024 Study Guide

To solve absolute value equations of the form $|f(x)|=g(x)$, solve $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f(x)=-g(x)$ and then check for extraneous solutions (i.e., those with $g(x)<0$).

The method they show simply does not always work.

I recommend the following approach: Case 1: $~x \geq 0.~$ Case 2: $~x < 0.$

How does you "intersection" work.  What do you do when you find the intersections?  Your tangent.  $2x=10\implies x=5$ and $2x=-10$ implies $x=-5$.  Now what? So what is the solution to $|2x| > 10$?  What is the solution to $|2x| < 10$? How does finding the "intersections" tell you what the solution is?  Do you then test $(-\infty, -5), (-5,5),$ and $ (5,\infty)$?  Or is the something else you do?  What if you test $(-\infty, \frac{28}{10}),(\frac{28}{10},7)$ and $(7, \infty)$?

For example if we try $x=0$ we get $|3x|=0$ and $28-7x=28$ and $0\not \ge 28$ so all of $(-\infty, \frac {28}{10})$ is out.  If we test $x=3$ we get $|3x|=9$ and $28-7x=7$ and $9\ge 7$ so $(\frac {28}{10})$ is in.  If we test $x=8$ we get $|3x|=24$ and $28-7x=-28$ and $24 \ge 24$ so $(7,\infty)$ is in.  .... Thing is we can only get $x=7$ and so $|3x|=-3x=28-7x$ when $|3x|=-3x$ and that is not the case when $x=7$.

The book is wrong for three reasons.
When you get the two inequalities $3x \ge 28- 7x$ and $-3x \ge 28 -7x$. these are two different cases.  So you don't combine them with an "AND" where they are both true.  You combine them with an "OR" where one or the other is true.
Second.  As we are assuming in the first case $|3x| =3x$ and in the second case that $|3x| = -3x$ we must take into account that $3x \ge 0$ in the first case, and $-3x \ge 0$ in the second.  The book didn't consider that at all.
Thirdly.  You don't flip just because you have a negative.  You flip only when you multiply by a negative.  If $|3x| \ge 28 -7x$ and $|3x| =-3x$ you will have $-3x =|3x| \ge 28 -7x$ and NOT $-3x \le 28-7x$.
....
The first inequality $3x \ge 28 -7x\implies x \ge \frac{28}{10}$ has to consider than also $3x \ge 0\implies x \ge 0$ so we conclude $x \ge \max(\frac {28}{10},0) = \frac{28}{10}$.
The second inequality $-3x \ge 28 -7x\implies 4x \ge 28\implies x \ge 7$ has to consider also that $-3x \ge 0\implies x \le 0$ so we have BOTH $x\ge 7$ and $x\le 0$.  That's impossible. so we never have $|3x| = -3x$.
Now to combine.  Well there's nothing to combine as the second case never happens... But if we did combine them it would have to be where we consider the two as an EITHER/OR and not an AND
(A union; not an intersection)

Thanks so much by why are we assuming X is positive or zero for one case and negative for the other. I’m confused by that.

Think about what the absolute value actually is. It is defined piecewise in terms of the original function. $|{f(x)}|= f(x)$ when $f(x)\geq 0$ and $|f(x)|=-f(x)$ when $f(x)<0$. So, these are the cases we must consider.

So why do we get 7 as an intersection when it’s not?

@Mick you don't, or rather it has to disappear immediately.  Changing $|\frac{3x}{7}|$ into $-\frac{3x}{7}$ brings with it the side condition of $\frac{3x}{7} \leq 0$ (because only when the thing inside the absolute-value bars is negative is the result of the absolute-value the flip).  Admittedly it's a pain to keep track of when solving, but you can enforce it at the end and just make that solution disappear.  Similarly, your first equation (where you just stripped the absolute value bars off and didn't flip anything) has a side condition as well (which you acknowledged that it satisfied).

Ok so it is until you see that 4-x would be negative if x=7 which makes no sense because an absolute value can’t be negative?

"So why do we get 7 as an intersection when it’s not?"  The intersection of $x \ge 7$ and $x\le 0$ is the empty set.  So we don't get it.

If you view it as an inequality yes but what if you simply ignore the inequalities and just attempt to find the intersections? Wouldn’t you do the same operations and land on x=7 as an answer?

"Ok so it is until you see that 4-x would be negative if x=7 which makes no sense because an absolute value can’t be negative? "  That's not actually a problem as the problem uses a GREATER THAN.  And an absolute value is always greater than a negative.  So if $4-x$ is negative we get $|\frac {3x}7| \ge 0 > 4-x$ and that will always be true.  Example if $x=16$ we will get $|\frac {3\times 16}7| \ge 0 \ge 4-16$. We don't even have to do math.

"If you view it as an inequality yes but what if you simply ignore the inequalities and just attempt to find the intersections? Wouldn’t you do the same operations and land on x=7 as an answer?" Even still, to have $-3x =28 -7x$ requires us to assume $x$ is not positive.  So when we end up with $x=7$ that contradicts $x$ is not positive.

Hmm.... I think you are more comfortable with $|M| = G \implies M = \pm G$ rather than $|M| = G \implies \pm M = G$.  But they are both the same.  If we do $|\frac {3x}7| = x-4$ we can see that as $\frac {3x}7 = x-4$ (which has to be positive or $0$) OR $\frac {3x}7 = 4-x$ (which has to be negative or $0$) The first give $x=\frac{28}{10}$ which is fine.  But the secon gives $x=7$ which is no good because we were assuming negative.

Thanks so much for this but now I tried another way I thought worked for every problem like this and got the wrong result from the book!! I did this. I found that (3x/7)=0 at x=0 and that 4-x=0 at x=4. I think separated the number like into three sections, where in each interval I know the sign of each expression.

I found that x<0 the left side is positive and right is negative, from 0 to 4 both sides of positive, and greater than 4 the left hand side is negative and right is positive. I then set up three equations: -(3x/7)>=4-x for the left interval, (3x/7)>=4-x for the middle interval, and (3x/7)>=-(4-x) for the right interval. I then found x>=7, x>=14/5, and x<=7. I threw away x>=7 because the condition was that x<0. So I arrived at a solution of 14/5<=x<=7. What did I do wrong?

Instead of deleting this in shame, I’ll comment here why I’m wrong. 4-x is always 4-x wherever it is on the number line. An absolute value changes.. so it makes sense to just consider when the absolute value is positive or negative and then solve the equations with that assumption in mind (so you can disregard solutions that can’t be possible). I.e., x>=7, when we know x<=0.

$$\begin{array}{l}
\left| {\frac{{3x}}{7}} \right| = 4 - x\\
 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
4 - x \ge 0\\
{\left( {\frac{{3x}}{7}} \right)^2} = {\left( {4 - x} \right)^2}
\end{array} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x \le 4\\
\left( {\frac{{3x}}{7} - \left( {4 - x} \right)} \right)\left( {\frac{{3x}}{7} + \left( {4 - x} \right)} \right) = 0
\end{array} \right.\\
 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x \le 4\\
\left( {\frac{{10x}}{7} - 4} \right)\left( {4 - \frac{{4x}}{7}} \right) = 0
\end{array} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x \le 4\\
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
x = \frac{{14}}{5}\\
x = 7
\end{array} \right.
\end{array} \right. \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{{14}}{5}
\end{array}$$
